# Simple division of a unit square into areas

Tags: graphics

Using Mathematica 11, I want to divide a $1\times 1$ graphic area into 4 areas divided into the following percentages  {.025,.075,.225,.675}. I've tried

```
RegionPlot[
x y <= .025 || x y >= .05 && x y <= .225 || 
x y > .25 && x y <= .675 || x y > .74, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
Mesh -> Full, ImageSize -> Small]

Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {.025, .025}], Blue, 
Rectangle[{.025, .025}, {.075, .075}], Green, 
Rectangle[{.075, .075}, {.225, .225}], Orange, 
Rectangle[{.225, .225}, {.675, .675}]}, 
PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, Frame -> True]

\[ScriptCapitalR] = 
ImplicitRegion[
x y == .025 || x y == .075 || x y == .225 || x y == .675, {x, y}];
RegionPlot[\[ScriptCapitalR], PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
GridLines -> Automatic]
```

Obviously, I don't know how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Obviously there are many ways to divide a unit square into 4 regions (unit-width rectangles come to mind). Which one are you looking for ?

Comment: Thanks, unit-width rectangles would be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple answer:

```
{a, b, c, d} = {.025, .075, .225, .675};
Graphics[{
  Red, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {a, 1}],
  Blue, Rectangle[{a, 0}, {a + b, 1}],
  Green, Rectangle[{a + b, 0}, {a + b + c, 1}],
  Orange, Rectangle[{a + b + c, 0}, {1, 1}]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you very much. At this point, your answer is just what I am looking for, though I would love to understand other ways to compare the areas perhaps  using Graphs or Inequalities. But I'm happy to start here. Thank you again.